# Slidingdrawer not closing

Tags: java, android

I created a simple SliderDrawer. When clicking on the handle it opens correctly but when clicked again it is not closing. I set up the onclick on the class so when the handle is clicked and the slidingdrawer is open it closes but not working. any idea why please?

Slider.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Slider extends Activity {

    SlidingDrawer sd;
    Button handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sliding);
        sd = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingD);
        handler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
        handler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(sd.isOpened() == true){
                    sd.animateClose();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

sliding.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >
        <!-- android:handle calls the button (Handle) -->
        <!-- android:content calls the linear layout (Hidden Content) -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cSlideable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CheckBox" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: maybe having the same id for the button and the handle is not a good idea?

Comment: from what I understand is that the button is the handler for the slidingdrawer. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: mine was actually a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to make it work was set the

> handler.OnClickListener

to

> (this)

and used the override onClick method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.handle:
            sd.close();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a drawer listener instead and it will save you the stress of handling the different states

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mListener);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html